# How to use datepicker in Spring MVC

Tags: jquery, hibernate, date, spring-mvc, datepicker

I am using Spring MVC for my Web apps, but I really don't know how to use Datepicker with Spring, because, way of Spring that data what from tag of spring is mapped into variable of corresponding Object via `path=""` property.But in my page which include Date component tof hat form tablig spring is not support this component.

Please help me!

And,There is a problem with this.Follow as:
After selecting or inputting value and submit but this value is not mapp into databse via hibernate

Comment: Please show some code of what you've tried so far and the problems/errors that you've had. It will help people answer your question.

Comment: Show us the error/problem/code?

Comment: Sorry.This haven't error.I mean I don't know how to use date component in Spring.Because,Spring only support <form:input> and so on without Date or Datepicker.I can't post my image because my quantity of  post isn't enought 10.Could you help me?

Answer (score 2):

if you use the  field set the path to your date object and use jquery (or some other javascript library) to generate a datepicker (like this one http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). and initialize your datepicker:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#date" ).datepicker(); // give your date field an id or a date css class
  });
</script>
```